# No Glow in Select Control of gwt-bootstrap

Tags: gwt, gwt-bootstrap

I activated gwt-bootstrap in my gwt application. But, I cannot see any glow in SELECT control. On the other hand, there is glow effect around the textarea control. How can I enable glow effect around SELECT control.

Following is my uibinder xml:

```
    <b:FluidContainer>
        <b:FluidRow>
            <b:Column size="4">
                <b:TextArea addStyleNames="input-block-level pull-right"></b:TextArea>
            </b:Column>
            <b:Column size="2">
                <g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="input-block-level"  >
                    <select multiple="multiple" class="input-block-level pull-left">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                    </select>
                </g:HTMLPanel>
            </b:Column>
        </b:FluidRow>
    </b:FluidContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its all in the css. Add following to your css and you might want to tweak it a bit to look exactly the same/suit your needs.

```
select:focus {
border-color: #52A8EF;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
outline: 0 none;
}
```